# VBA - finding column position within a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of contiguous data, say A1:F10.

In B1:F1 are dates for the past week. My code searches for yesterday's date, then inserts a column to the right. In cells A2:A10 are names of fruit, the rest of the cells have random numbers of fruit.

What I want to do is loop through all the fruits in Col A and enter a value (say 1) in the column I inserted to the right of yesterday's date if the fruit is an orange. The only ranges I can define are the A1:F10 using currentRegion and yesterday's date using entireColumn from .find.

Does anyone know how to loop through col A and enter a value into the newly inserted column (which can be in a different place each time the sheet is generated)? I think it could be done using offset and some combination of columns/cells using the cell with yesterday's date in row 1 as a reference as the blank column will always be to the right of this.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the complicated explanation.

```
Dim myDate As Date

myDate = Application.InputBox("Please enter the date (DD/MM/YY)")

'Find yesterday's date in row 1

Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Find(What:=myDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Set Yesterday = ActiveCell

For Each mycell In range("A:A")

  If Left(mycell.Value, 4) = "Oran" Then

      mycell.Offset(0, Not sure what to put here).Value = 1

  End If

Next
```

Not sure what to put here = I think this is something to do with the yesterday variable +1 but not too sure

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So at the moment yesterday's date is stored as myDate and is = to Date() - 1. I call the find function on row 1 and it finds it. I then assign a variable to the activeCell called Yesterday. I don't know how to incorporate the variable yesterday (col I want to go to) into the offset. Are you able to help me?

Comment: The column you want is equal to `Yesterday.Column + 1`. On a related note, you assume that you'll always find yesterday's date... You want to add error handling in case  you don't.

Comment: Thanks, I will put in error handling. For some reason (and I cannot understand why), it puts it 5 columns on from yesterday +1, do you have any idea why?